# using twitter4j api timeline selection error

Tags: twitter

I encounter problem
I don't understand this problem

403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
    message - SSL is required
    code - 92

```
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
   http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ced778ef or
   http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0baf6933
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[ced778ef-0baf6933], statusCode=403, message=SSL is required, code=92, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{remaining=178, limit=180, resetTimeInSeconds=1395054377, secondsUntilReset=705}, version=3.0.3}
   at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:177)
   at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
   at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:81)
   at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1835)
   at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getUserTimeline(TwitterImpl.java:153)
   at UserTimeline.main(UserTimeline.java:85)
```

please help me thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter have restricted all api traffic to SSL on the 14th Jan 2014 as mentioned in their blog (https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239). You need to upgrade your Twitter4j to version 4 (http://blog.twitter4j.org/2014/03/12/66)